# Changing bot difficulty in Dominion Online

Tags: dominion, online, computer-ai

Regarding the new online version of the deck-building card game Dominion, my friend complains that the bot is too challenging. Is there any way to decrease the difficulty when playing bots 1-on-1 in Dominion Online?

Comment: I recommend your friend keep playing more and learning Dominion better. The bot is, to be frank, pretty terrible at Dominion.

Comment: Hah, fair enough. The friend is new, and I'm very happy they are making a good-faith attempt at learning the game. But let's face it, we were all there at some point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not currently any difficulty settings for the AI.

I cannot find an official source stating this to quote/link as reference, but you can read through the [official FAQ](http://forum.shuffleit.nl/index.php?topic=1100.0) and see some mentions of playing against the AI, with no mention of a difficulty setting.

As this is a pretty new implementation of the game, it is constantly in development with improvements and bug fixes happening often. So it is reasonable to expect such functionality to happen; though I have not heard about any expected timeline or priority for that feature. You can request that feature at the [feature requests board](http://forum.shuffleit.nl/index.php?board=11.0) on the Shuffle iT forums.

Comment: Thanks for the very thoughtful and informative reply! I thought that was the case (i.e. I tried and failed to locate such a setting), thank you for confirmation. Also, I'm pretty hyped that such an esteemed player answered my question!

Comment: @ancientcampus You're welcome.. but I have to ask, what makes you think I am "an esteemed player"? Did you see my frequency of the Dominion Strategy Forums? There was a time, back in the days of Isotropic (over 4 years ago), that I was a pretty high-ranked player, but not so much anymore.

Comment: I confess I have played little Dominion in the past 4 years, so that seems about right. If I recall, your posts on the Dominion Strategy forums were frequent and well-received. Yours is one of the few names I remember from those days.

Comment: Update: browsing the feature requests board confirms this. Multiple bot difficulties is not presently implemented.